# SocketTimeoutException while trying to reach Gmail API from Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gmail-api

I'm running automated tests that call the Gmail API.

I'm going to say it (are you ready?): *It works on my machine*.

But when I run the same tests via Jenkins, I get a `SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out` error.

Some addresses have been added to the proxy's whitelist (but with no improvement):

- `accounts.google.com`
- `gmail.googleapis.com`

Where it fails:

```
JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
String APPLICATION_NAME = "TEST";

final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
// This one runs ok
Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
    .build();
// It fails here:
ListMessagesResponse response = service.
    users().
    messages().
    list("me").
    setQ("subject:" + messageTitle).
    execute();
```

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: Check the network configuration on the system that is running Jenkins. Can it actually connect to the outside world?

Comment: @JimGarrison I think so, but how to be sure?

Comment: Try connecting to the outside world?

Comment: @accessviolation Jenkins is running behind a proxy and in fact, I couldn't even access Google home page (I tested this just now). But Google home page isn't my goal, that's why I asked to allow `accounts.google.com` & `gmail.googleapis.com`. It seems that it's not enough, but I don't know which resource I must ask to allow.

Comment: Do you need to tell your transport that a proxy is being used? https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport#com_google_api_client_googleapis_javanet_GoogleNetHttpTransport_newTrustedTransport__

Comment: @tgdavies thanks for the idea, I tried this but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: If your jenkins is behind a (corporate) proxy, chances are high you are using something like cntlm to setup a local proxy? If so, you can ssh to your jenkins and use "journalctl -u cntlm.service -f" to see which URLs are called. Depending on the setup or the tooling you might need to adapt the params a bit.

Comment: Show full error stacktrace

Comment: @Y-BCause do you use any kind of containers in your jenkins pipeline? e.g. Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally found how to fix the problem. It was, as expected, a proxy issue. My virtual machine was running behind a certain corporate proxy, and the Jenkins instance was running behind *another one*.

Instead of `final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();`

I put a custom `final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = (NetHttpTransport) newProxyTransport();`

Which is defined here:

```
protected static Boolean isJenkinsMode = Boolean.getBoolean(System.getProperty("jenkinsMode"));

static HttpTransport newProxyTransport() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    NetHttpTransport.Builder builder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
    builder.trustCertificates(GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore());
    String proxy = "default-proxy-address-which-works-on-my-machine.com";
    if(isJenkinsMode){
        proxy = "proxy-address-for-jenkins.com";
    }
    builder.setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxy, 3128)));
    return builder.build();
}
```

Then, from Jenkins, I run the Maven command with `-DjenkinsMode=true`.